# Setting up Spark jobserver on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-jobserver

I am trying to setup spark job server on my YARN
I am doing

```
./bin/server_package.sh ec2
```

This make a folder in `/tmp/jobserver`
When i try to `./sever_start.sh`

I receive this error

```
Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[JobServer]
Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[JobServer]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ooyala/common/akka/ActorMetrics$$anonfun$receive$1
        at ooyala.common.akka.ActorMetrics$class.receive(ActorMetrics.scala:20)
        at ooyala.common.akka.InstrumentedActor.receive(InstrumentedActor.scala:8)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:558)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[JobServer]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ooyala/common/akka/ActorMetrics$$anonfun$receive$1
        at ooyala.common.akka.ActorMetrics$class.receive(ActorMetrics.scala:20)
        at ooyala.common.akka.InstrumentedActor.receive(InstrumentedActor.scala:8)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:558)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:578)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:478)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:263)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
```

Tried reducing version of akka no effect
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using same version of sbt to build as the version with which spark jobserver is built?

Comment: Yes
I am able to run job server on local machine via sbt
But when I package it and try to run it on yarn I get this error

Comment: If this is an acceptable answer, can you select this as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be in conflicting versions of scala used.
Spark was on 2.11.7 while job server was on 2.10.4

Answer (score 0):

Always try to match the scala version of Spark and spark job-server. The version should be the same in ec2.sh/local.sh as the scala version you see in spark-shell.